# How to get selected option inside href link in HTML using Django for backend

Tags: html, django

I have 3 drop down menus. each menu takes it's values through variable passed through object context. here is the view function:

```
def home_page(request):

    template = 'path/to/template.html'

    cities = City.objects.all()
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()

    all_sub_category = Sub_Category.objects.all()

    context={
        'cities': cities,
        'all_categories': all_categories,
        'all_sub_category': all_sub_category,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

the template is as follow:

```
   {% load staticfiles %}


<select>
        {% for city in cities %}
    <option value='{{city.city_name}}'>
        {{city.city_name}}
    </option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>

<select>
        {% for category in all_categories %}
    <option value='{{category.category_name}}'>
        {{category.category_name}}
    </option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>

<select>
        {% for sub_category in all_sub_category %}
    <option value='{{sub_category.sub_category_name}}' >
        {{sub_category.sub_category_name }}
    </option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>

<a href="http://domain_name/towns/{{city.city_name}}/{{category.category_name}}/{{sub_category.sub_category_name}}"><span > move to next page  </span>  </a>
```

the problem is that the resultant URL is missing all three variables even though all variables are displayed in the drop down menus. here is the resultant link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/towns///
```

I tried also the following href:

```
href="http://domain_name/towns/{{city.city_name.0}}/{{category.category_name.0}}/{{sub_category.sub_category_name.0}}"><span > move to next page  </span>  </a>
```

any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done doesn't work because `city` variable does not exist outside the for loop.
 Similarly for other variables

The best way to do this is wrap all the select tags in a form. Then send the form via GET/POST to a view. Then from that view, you can redirect to the url that you want.

You can also use javascript to redirect to the url directly from the template, but I feel what I mentioned above is much cleaner